# How to better visualize Networkx self loop plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx

How can I plot the self-loop larger, it is small and does not look good.
[image]

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(my_graph.vertex_list)
G.add_weighted_edges_from(my_graph.edges_list)
weight = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')
nx.draw_networkx(G, with_labels=True, pos=my_graph.position, node_size= 200, node_color='r',
                 edge_color='g',
                 arrowsize=23, font_size=16)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, my_graph.position, edge_labels=weight, font_size=16)
nx.to_pandas_edgelist(G)
nx.to_pandas_adjacency(G)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question. The easy (but unreliable) fix imo is to change the figure size:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edge('A','A')
G.add_edge('A','B')
G.add_edge('C','B')
G.add_edge('D','B')

pos = {'A':(0,1),'B':(1,1),'C':(0,0),'D':(1,0)}

G['A']['B']['weight'] = 1
G['C']['B']['weight'] = 1
G['D']['B']['weight'] = 1

weight = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,20))

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos = pos, node_size= 800, node_color='r')
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos = pos, font_size = 23)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos = pos, edge_labels=weight, font_size=23)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos = pos, edge_color='g', arrowsize=50, node_size = 800)

plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]

How I would do it to have some more control: Look into how the paths are generated and mimic the generation of them in the networkx package[(source of networkx_draw_edges)](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.html#draw_networkx_edges):

```
class SelfLoop():
    def __init__(self, v_scale=0.25, h_scale=0.25, nodesize=100):
        self.v_scale = v_scale
        self.h_scale = h_scale
        self.nodesize = nodesize

    def selfloopstyle(self, posA, posB, *args, **kwargs):
        from matplotlib.path import Path

        selfloop_ht = 0.005 * self.nodesize

        data_loc = ax.transData.inverted().transform(posA)
        v_shift = self.v_scale * selfloop_ht
        h_shift = v_shift * self.h_scale

        path = [
            data_loc + np.asarray([0, v_shift]),
            data_loc + np.asarray([h_shift, v_shift]),
            data_loc + np.asarray([h_shift, 0]),
            data_loc,
            data_loc + np.asarray([-h_shift, 0]),
            data_loc + np.asarray([-h_shift, v_shift]),
            data_loc + np.asarray([0, v_shift]),
        ]

        ret = Path(ax.transData.transform(path), [1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4])

        return ret
    
    def style(self):
        return self.selfloopstyle
```

Now you have to manipulate the self loops which were created by networkx. Change the `_connector` attribute of the edges and reapply them to the axes-object.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edge('A','A')
G.add_edge('A','B')
G.add_edge('C','B')
G.add_edge('D','B')
G.add_edge('D','D')

pos = {'A':(0,1),'B':(1,1),'C':(0,0),'D':(1,0)}

G['A']['A']['weight'] = 1
G['A']['B']['weight'] = 1
G['C']['B']['weight'] = 1
G['D']['B']['weight'] = 1
G['D']['D']['weight'] = 1

weight = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')



fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos = pos, node_size= 800, node_color='r')
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos = pos, font_size = 23)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos = pos, edge_labels=weight, font_size=23)

e = nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos = pos, edge_color='g', arrowsize=50, node_size = 800)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos = pos, edge_labels=weight, font_size=23)

e[0]._connector = SelfLoop(1,1).style() #select self loop and change connector
ax.add_patch(e[0]) #add the patch to ax 

e[-1]._connector = SelfLoop(-2,1).style()
ax.add_patch(e[-1])

ax.autoscale_view() #rescale so all edges are shown

plt.show()
```

Result, with different self loops:
[image: Result with class]

I appreciate suggestions on how you could do this better.

Comment: This answer is awesome!! Wondering if you have thoughts on how to flip the self-loops so that they come out of the side of the node, instead of the top or bottom? At the moment making the horizontal value negative just flips the direction of the arrow, which makes total sense -- but I'd like to do something like making the loop on A come out of the top and bottom of the node and stick out to the left, instead of coming from the left and right and sticking out to the top